# How to reformat a CSV who's columns are occasionally thrown off

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-cleaning

I have CSV data that is occasionally disrupted by a rogue comma when it is output from a server. What would be the easiest way to concatenate the title to the intended format either using Pandas or CSV reader/writer?
[image]

I have tried to check the length of each row but get the same output each time and the exception is never flagged.

Comment: In the general case, I don't think it can be done. If you can articulate constraints on the columns (like, the third one should always be a number, or the second one should contain a label in a particular format), this is probably doable, but your example is too small to attempt to generalize from. (Also, please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557))

Comment: Is switching to `'\t'` as a separator and then excluding all commas from the recieved csv an option?

Comment: Do you have null values except for the columns that are ill-created?

Comment: As first comment says, we need more information about it. A good way to approach this would be to assume that every row has exactly as many datafields as the head and an emtpy data field is always an error and not valid data. Then we could just read all rows and remove the empty fields so that the following fields are shifted to the left.

Comment: What program is outputting it from the server?